# Connection issues with iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch, wifi

I have one year old iPod Touch. All of a sudden YouTube is not working. I have wireless network at home.

It says "Cannot connect to YouTube". I'm also facing this issue when I connect to Gmail. it says - "Cannot connect to imap...". but still I can see my mail.

I guess it shouldn't be issues with wireless or n/w connectivity because Safari browsing is working fine.

Comment: @HanuAthena I tried to change the title to better reflect the nature of the issue (I'm not sure I have though...). It is generally a good idea to be fairly specific with the title.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue for a few weeks.  I found that the problem was with my firewall.  Even though I had told the firewall to allow all traffic to and from my ipod, it still didn't work because the firewall slowed down the internet tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest Resetting Network Settings first for connectivity issues. Settings >> General >> Reset >> Reset Network Settings. Then connect to your network again. If that doesn't work, post back here.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion on any problem with technical devices is to shut down properly and restart the device. To shut down, hold down the sleep/wake button for a few seconds until the iPod asks you if you want to shut down.