# iPod touch stopped playing the Pandora app with the following error: "Cannot Connect to Pandora"

Tags: applications, ipod-touch, ipod, ipod.app

An iPod Touch with the following specs:

- 2<sup>nd</sup> Generation
- Version 4.2.1 (8C148)
- Model: MC086LL

Stopped playing the Pandora app. with the following error:

> **Cannot Connect to Pandora**
>
> Please check your network connection and try again later.

This iPod Touch was working fine 2 weeks ago then starting getting this error. I'm connected to the internet and other apps like Safari work fine.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Whom should I reach out to for this issue?

Comment: @Thomas This did not work:-( http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/2166/62040 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! The solution was to set the Date to the correct Date. It was set to 1969 for some reason:-/

- Settings->General->Date&Time

Comment: That stinks! :) I'm glad you discovered that :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ap Store and check for pending updates

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with my iPhone (3rd gen) and iPod Touch with Pandora.
Cured both with simply powering off, waiting about 30 seconds then powering back on.